# Relativistic non-linear Walecka model

Tags: soft-question, nuclear-physics, terminology, hadron-dynamics

What is meant by a [**relativistic non-linear Walecka model**](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=relativistic+nonlinear+walecka+model)?

What are some various sources to study it?

[And why cannot Google show a satisfactory result to such a simple question?]

Comment: *"And why cannot Google show a satisfactory result to such a simple question?]"* Searching based on plain text doesn't deal well with restrictive adjectives because there is a context dependency that is neglected (or treated with fairly rough heuristics). The place to start is in understanding what a Walecka model is in general (a meson exchange based model of nuclear physics, I believe), and only then understand what the adjectives imply.

Comment: @dmckee Where can I learn about the Walecka model then? Any source or paper..give me a link.

Comment: Uhm ... he wrote a book. *Nuclear and Subnuclear Physics*, I think. And the lecure notes from his theory lectures when he was the first director of Jefferson lab might be on the web, or you could just google for the exact phrase ["Walecka model"](https://www.google.com/search?q="walecka+model"), and then sort through the links that merely mention the phrase in search of one that defines and explains it.

Comment: I see that you found http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126533/why-does-the-walecka-model-not-include-pions . I'm linking it here for any one else who comes along later.